# Why isn't there a server edition for Fedora like Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

I was looking for a server edition of Fedora to download, and just found that they don't have one. It's very strange to me. If Ubuntu has both desktop and server editions, why doesn't Fedora follow suit?

Comment: There is. It's called [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://www.redhat.com/products/enterprise-linux/), and you're expected to buy it.

Comment: There's no difference between server and desktop, all just different kernel and package installations.

Comment: RHEL is a paid version, CentOS and Scientific are free.

Comment: *What* prevents you from installing Fedora Core as a server?

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28647/11284

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fedora <del>only has a Desktop edition</del>has [Server edition](https://getfedora.org/en/server/).  In my experience, "server" distros have a longer support lifetime than desktop distros.  If you want something that has a longer support cycle, use Red Hat Enterprise Linux, or [one of the RHEL clones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_derivatives) like CentOS.  Fedora really isn't suited for a long-term support OS, because at best you'll get [13 months of support](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Release_Life_Cycle) if you install a release the day it comes out (Unlike [RHEL](http://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/)).

While Fedora is really only aimed at the desktop, the OS certainly supports being installed as a server, using the DVD or network installer.  RHEL6 is based on Fedora 12 (with backports from later Fedoras and security fixes) and uses the same installation software as Fedora, so there's nothing stopping you from using Fedora as a server OS, just don't expect to get updates or security fixes past the end of its support lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

RedHat Enterprise Linux *is* Fedora server.

[Fedora is where RedHat innovates](http://www.redhat.com/resourcelibrary/articles/relationship-between-fedora-and-rhel) and so it's bleeding edge by definition and not meant for servers. RedHat Enterprise is based on Fedora. Fedora provides a platform to develop and test new updates before they get pushed to RedHat Enterprise.

This is why [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) gets the newest stuff before other distributions. This makes Fedora a great desktop OS for early adopters who like to get the new stuff first, but for servers, you want battle tested code, not bleeding edge.

Fedora is such an asset to RedHat because by the time something makes it into RedHat Enterprise, the code has been hardened after being battle tested in the wild by millions of users.

RedHat has been in the game for a long time pushing Linux development, and the Fedora model has proven effective. RedHat's first release was in 1995, Fedora was released in 2003, and in 2012 [RedHat became the first billion dollar open-source company](http://www.informationweek.com/development/open-source/red-hat-first-1-billion-open-source-comp/232700454).

In essence, [Fedora is RedHat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) before the addition of [RedHat Enterprise Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux). The name was changed to reduce confusion, but the project's importance was made clear when they renamed it after RedHat's iconic symbol -- its red fedora.

See the [Red Hat/Fedora project announcement](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-list/2003-September/msg00064.html).

Running Fedora on your desktop keeps you at the forefront of Linux development world ([it's what Linus uses](http://news.oreilly.com/2008/07/linux-torvalds-on-linux-distri.html)), and it makes your life easier if you're running RedHat or CentOS servers because the environments are the same. In contrast, if you run RedHat on your servers and Ubuntu on your desktop, you have different package managers, file system layout, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora as a server does work fine, but its short lifetime make it a hassle (**must** upgrade due to end-of-life just in the middle of finals or such...).

Fedora isn't "aimed at the desktop", it's driving force is to get the newest bling out. That happens to be what the desktop users demand...